# Как в одном модуле обработать несколько UIAlertView?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Как различить, какой из UIAlertView обрабатывается функцией

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex?
```

Comment: сделал ягодичным методом: через переменные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть свойство у UIView `tag`  оно UIInteger типа, используется как раз для идентификации объектов.
помечайте

```
UIAlertView  *alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" message:@"Message send succesfull" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertView setTag:1];
```

ну и в делегате проверочку

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        if(alertView.tag == 1){
              //something clever
        }
}
```

Да в obj-c бедные программисты не могут из коробки юзать стринги  для идентификации, но и switch/case стринги не умеет обрабатывать, а тут можно enum в тег затолкать и радоваться хоть так.

Comment: Супер! я догадывался, что должно быть, как-то просто.